# Scoreboard In Minecraft

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-commands

I wanted to know how to *make a scoreboard* That Knows What **Cordinates** You are at,
and one that I can actually make text in, because I can put text, but only numbers for the answer.
Is is something like...

''
/scoreboard players add {text} {name} {score}
''?

P.S., I tried /scoreboard players add {text} {name} {score}, but when I do it, it does not allow me to put text in for the score.

If I was able to do that, I would create that, but, Another thing...

Am i able to create one with animated text in vanilla Minecraft?

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. This site is for programming questions. For game related questions it might be better to ask on [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) and for game-development specific questions on [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) SE sites.

Answer (score 0):

Scoreboards can only hold short integer values. The name of the value (key, property, entry, objective or whatever you want to call it) however is a String, with not too many limitaitons. For display purposes generally this is used - you might have seen scoreboards on some servers where the left side had the information as text and the right side consisted of numbers 1-10.

Unfortunately, it is not possible to dynamically create scoreboard entries via commands or command blocks. You have to use plugins or datapacks for that. (I'm unsure whether this is doable with datapacks, but you should be able to research that on your own). While plugins are not considered vanilla, datapacks are a part of the minecraft environment.

For more information about scoreboards you can read https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Scoreboard.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create a scoreboard, use `scoreboard objectives add <name> <type> <display JSON (optional)>`
your current command, `scoreboard players add` is used for adding values to one's score.
there is a score json component, which you can use in the display name creating an objective, but that is about as dynamic scoreboard names get.

this might not be what you want, but you can get a players coordinates in a scoreboard. here are some commands to do so:
run the following command once:

```
scoreboard objectives add pos dummy // creates scoreboard only modifiable with commands (dummy)
```

run the commands after this repeating, in a repeating command block or your tick function, if you are using datapacks.

```
execute as <player> store result score x pos run data get entity @s Pos[0]
execute as <player> store result score y pos run data get entity @s Pos[1]
execute as <player> store result score z pos run data get entity @s Pos[2]
```

these command store the player's various position data into a score, which you will then be able to see on the scoreboard, which can be displayed with `scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar pos`

let me know if you have more questions. note the solution i provided only works for one player, for others it is a little more complicated.